# Map all request to one method

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler

I want to map all request from http://www.mydomain.com/{any url path} to one method and decided to use code below. Unfortunately I get 404, why?

Config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Processor" verb="*" path="*.*"
        type="WebClient.Processor,WebClient" />
    </handlers>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Code

```
namespace WebClient
{

    public class Processor : IHttpHandler
    {

        #region IHttpHandler Members




        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {


         //Read all request here, but never hit

        }



        public bool IsReusable
        {
            // Return false in case your Managed Handler cannot be reused for another request.
            // Usually this would be false in case you have some state information preserved per request.
            get { return true; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: what is the full config here? for example, is IIS perhaps configured to check for the existence of files?

Comment: @MarcGravell I have update post and inserted full config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found where is the problem. In config file instead of path="*.*" should be path="*"

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the existing handlers inherited from machine config, if you want to remap paths like `*.aspx` for instance.

```
<handlers>
  <clear />
  <add name="Processor" verb="*" path="*" 
                             type="WebClient.Processor,WebClient" />
</handlers>
```